# odd positive roots of basic classical Lie superalgebras

Tags: weyl-group, lie-superalgebras

In the Lie algebra case, positive roots are "almost ($S_{\alpha}$ permutes $\Delta^+ -\{\alpha\}$)" invariant under simple reflections. A similar statement I want to understand for Lie superalgebras.

Let $\mathfrak g =  \mathfrak g_0 \oplus \mathfrak g_1$ be a basic classical Lie superalgebra and let $W$ be the Weyl group of $\mathfrak g_0$

My question is, whether $\Delta_1^+$ is invariant under $W$?

More generally what is $w \cdot \big(\sum_{\alpha \in \Delta^+_1} \alpha\big)$ for $w \in W$ ?

kindly share your thoughts and thank you.